# mongodb is not using an index for a find command

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query

I have approximately 40M documents in a mongo collection. There is an index on the `location.country` field:

```
MongoDB Enterprise cluster-0-shard-0:PRIMARY> db.cases.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_"
    },
//...
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "location.country" : -1
        },
        "name" : "countriesIdx",
        "collation" : {
            "locale" : "en_US",
            "caseLevel" : false,
            "caseFirst" : "off",
            "strength" : 2,
            "numericOrdering" : false,
            "alternate" : "non-ignorable",
            "maxVariable" : "punct",
            "normalization" : false,
            "backwards" : false,
            "version" : "57.1"
        }
    },
//...
]
```

But queries don't use it:

```
MongoDB Enterprise cluster-0-shard-0:PRIMARY> db.cases.find({'location.country':'ghana'}).explain({verbosity: 'executionStats'})
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "covid19.cases",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "location.country" : {
                "$eq" : "ghana"
            }
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
            "filter" : {
                "location.country" : {
                    "$eq" : "ghana"
                }
            },
            "direction" : "forward"
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
    },
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 0,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 195892,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 0,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 39264034,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
            "filter" : {
                "location.country" : {
                    "$eq" : "ghana"
                }
            },
            "nReturned" : 0,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 99032,
            "works" : 39264036,
            "advanced" : 0,
            "needTime" : 39264035,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 39503,
            "restoreState" : 39503,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "direction" : "forward",
            "docsExamined" : 39264034
        },
        "allPlansExecution" : [ ]
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "cluster-0-shard-00-01-vwhx6.mongodb.net",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "4.4.8",
        "gitVersion" : "83b8bb8b6b325d8d8d3dfd2ad9f744bdad7d6ca0"
    },
    "ok" : 1,
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1629732226, 1),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"piKWDwLDv7FRcnwCe51PZDLR4UM="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong("6958739380580122625")
        }
    },
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1629732226, 1)
}
```

Do I need to set up the index differently or do something else to get mongo to use the index? I have tried to `hint` that it should, but it still does a `COLLSCAN`. While the examples I've shown above are using `mongosh`, the behaviour is the same in my node app using `mongoose`.

Comment: You need to specify the collation option in your query too.

Comment: @prasad_ thank you, perfect, execution time down to 9ms!

Comment: Unfortunately in my app, I already specify the collation, and the query is still slow there. I'll have to do more with the explainer to discover why.